# CakePHP Global slug router

Tags: cakephp, seo, router, slug

I have configured slugs for all my posts and I need the `Router` that will do the links like:

`/controller/post_slug_name`
and I need this for all the controllers, but when I go with:

```
Router::connect('/admin', array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'settings', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
Router::connect('/:controller/:slug', array('action' => 'index'), array('pass' => array('slug')));
```

The admin panel is not working. How can I make it like this, simple, and with admin panel working? Thanks

**EDIT:
With those tree routers is working as I would like, except that in the control panel I am getting even the index actions in the urls and not cool**

```
Router::connect('/admin', array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'settings', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
Router::connect('/admin/:controller/:action/*', array('admin' => true));
Router::connect('/:controller/:slug', array('action' => 'index'), array('pass' => array('slug')));
```

Comment: What does the admin route have to do with the slug route?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this so I am not sure it works, but please try the following...

```
Router::connect('/:controller/:slug', array('action' => 'view:slug'));
```

You view function also needs to accept $slug as paramenter:

```
function view($slug){
     ...
}
```

If the above does not work, you could try this as well:

```
Router::connect('/:controller/*',array('action' => 'view'));
```

Once again, I have not tried any of these codes and dont know if any works, just putting ideas outthere. When I get home I will them.

Thanks,

Comment: The first `Router` does not work for both admin panel and frontend.
The second one works only for the frontend and giving error `Error: AdminController could not be found.` when trying to go to the admin panel, just like the first code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

try connecting `/admin/*` instead of just `/admin`

Comment: like this, no matter what the controller is, i am getting the `'controller' => 'settings', 'action' => 'dashboard'`

Comment: I use the '/admin' route as well and it works for me, what exactly does it render when you access /admin url
does it report a warning, anything in the log?!